# Save recorded gif (base64 string) as gif in certain directory with ajax

Tags: php, jquery

My problem is, I recorded a gif with the gifshot.js plugin and want to save it now what does not waork. I use an ajax function to send the src string to a php which then decodes the base64 string (works properly). After that happened the gif shall be saved in the directory you will see down below but it just wont work. Very frustrated... Do you have any approaches?

HTML:

```
<section id="reingif" class="gifshot-image-preview-section" style="height: 210.7px; width: 210.7px;">
    <img src="data:image/gif;base64,ROIGODIh9AH0AQAAA...">
</section>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#create-gif").click(function(){      
    gifshot.createGIF({
        gifWidth: 500,
        gifHeight: 500,
        interval: 0.2,
        numFrames: 25,
        sampleInterval:7,
        numWorkers: 3
    }, function (obj) {
        if (!obj.error) {

            var image = obj.image, animatedImage = document.createElement('img');
            animatedImage.src = image;
            $("#reingif").html(animatedImage);

            var viewportHeight  = $(window).height();
            var gifdims         = 0.7 * viewportHeight + "px";
            $("#reingif img").addClass("addcrimg").height(gifdims).width(gifdims);

            var datastring = $("#reingif img").attr('src');
            $.ajax({ 
                url: 'savegif.php',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'text',
                data: { 'base64data' : datastring }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

php:

```
@$base64data = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST["username"])));

$decodedpic = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $base64data));

file_put_contents('/images/saved.gif', $decodedpic);
```

Comment: Do you have any error messages for us? You are also using file_put_contents with an absolute path. You most likely do not have an /images/ folder on your server. You might want to try some variant of `file_put_contents(__DIR__.'/../images/saved.gif', $decodedpic);`

Comment: Why are you running mysqli_real_escape_string and htmlspecialchars over a form submission that you want to write to a file on disk?

Comment: The _POST variable you are reading (username) is also not provided by the AJAX call.

Comment: @colburton thanks for helping... too many stupid mistakes in one excerpt of code... Really thankful !!

Comment: @iainn thanks for helping... too many stupid mistakes in one excerpt of code... Really thankful !!